# Обработка нажатия на клавиши в pyqt

Tags: pyqt4

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на какую-нибудь клавишу с клавиатуры выполнялась какая-та функция. Например тут:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.one)
```

при нажатии на кнопку self.pushButton выполняется функция self.one, но непонятно как заменить self.pushButton, например, на клавишу пробел.
ОС - убунту 14.04, если что :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем классе (наследнике `QWidget`) вы можете переопределять обработчики различных событий.

Вас интересует обработка нажатия клавиш - переопределите метод

```
virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
```

Тестовый пример:

```
class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print("pressed key " + str(event.key()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tst = TestWidget()
    tst.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Программа печатает в консоли код нажатой кнопки.